# Why is FormBodyWrapperFilter necessary in Spring cloud Zuul?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

In a simple `@EnableZuulProxy` application, requests with Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` gets wrapped in a `FormBodyRequestWrapper` by `FormBodyWrapperFilter`. This decodes the content and reencode it for the backend.

However, from what I can see, requests of other content types (let's say `application/json`) in a service discovery enabled route will get their `InputStream` directly proxied to the client used through the `RibbonCommandContext`.

In Apache `HttpClient` for example, the input stream will be wrapped in a `BasicHttpEntity` in the `RibbonApacheHttpRequest`.

Why is this necessary? Couldn't we just handle all requests the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/109 for the original issue.

The zuul request wrapper buffers the request and it needed to be added back for the proxy. This is one of the reasons spring cloud gateway was built, since it doesn't have these problems.

Comment: Just to add a precision, `com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` does the buffering and not the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: Edited my answer